# fix inner div at the top of outer div and when scrolling outer div, prevent inner div overflowing on the outer div

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have been trying to fix a inner div at the top of an outer div. 

 1.The inner div should have a wider width than the outer div

 2.The outer div is scrollable and inner div should remain at the top of the outer div while scrolling.

My problem is that the inner div longer stays inside the outer div.

---

```
<div id="ScheduleHolder" style="height:100px; width:120px; overflow:scroll">

    <div id="2" valign="top" style="float:none; display:block; position:absolute !important; margin:0;">

        <table border="1" bgcolor="#99FF00">

          <tr>

            <th scope="col">&nbsp;</th>

            <th scope="col">&nbsp;</th>

            <th scope="col">&nbsp;</th>

            <th scope="col">&nbsp;</th>

            <th scope="col">&nbsp;</th>

            <th scope="col">&nbsp;</th>

            <th scope="col">&nbsp;</th>

            <th scope="col">&nbsp;</th>

            <th scope="col">&nbsp;</th>

            <th scope="col">&nbsp;</th>

            <th scope="col">&nbsp;</th>

            <th scope="col">&nbsp;</th>

            <th scope="col">&nbsp;</th>



          </tr>

        </table> 

    </div>



    <div id="3" style="float:left; display:block;">

       <table border="1">

          <tr>

            <th scope="col">&nbsp;</th>

            <th scope="col">&nbsp;</th>

            <th scope="col">&nbsp;</th>

            <th scope="col">&nbsp;</th>

            <th scope="col">&nbsp;</th>

            <th scope="col">&nbsp;</th>

            <th scope="col">&nbsp;</th>

            <th scope="col">&nbsp;</th>

            <th scope="col">&nbsp;</th>

            <th scope="col">&nbsp;</th>

            <th scope="col">&nbsp;</th>

            <th scope="col">&nbsp;</th>

            <th scope="col">&nbsp;</th>



          </tr>

          <tr>

            <th scope="row">&nbsp;</th>

            <td>&nbsp;</td>

            <td>&nbsp;</td>

            <td>&nbsp;</td>

            <td>&nbsp;</td>

            <td>&nbsp;</td>

            <td>&nbsp;</td>

                            <td>&nbsp;</td>

            <td>&nbsp;</td>

            <td>&nbsp;</td>

            <td>&nbsp;</td>

            <td>&nbsp;</td>

            <td>&nbsp;</td>

          </tr>

          <tr>

            <th scope="row">&nbsp;</th>

            <td>&nbsp;</td>

            <td>&nbsp;</td>

            <td>&nbsp;</td>

            <td>&nbsp;</td>

            <td>&nbsp;</td>

            <td>&nbsp;</td>

                            <td>&nbsp;</td>

            <td>&nbsp;</td>

            <td>&nbsp;</td>

            <td>&nbsp;</td>

            <td>&nbsp;</td>

            <td>&nbsp;</td>

          </tr>

          <tr>

            <th scope="row">&nbsp;</th>

            <td>&nbsp;</td>

            <td>&nbsp;</td>

            <td>&nbsp;</td>

            <td>&nbsp;</td>

            <td>&nbsp;</td>

            <td>&nbsp;</td>

                            <td>&nbsp;</td>

            <td>&nbsp;</td>

            <td>&nbsp;</td>

            <td>&nbsp;</td>

            <td>&nbsp;</td>

            <td>&nbsp;</td>

          </tr>

          <tr>

            <th scope="row">&nbsp;</th>

            <td>&nbsp;</td>

            <td>&nbsp;</td>

            <td>&nbsp;</td>

            <td>&nbsp;</td>

            <td>&nbsp;</td>

            <td>&nbsp;</td>

                            <td>&nbsp;</td>

            <td>&nbsp;</td>

            <td>&nbsp;</td>

            <td>&nbsp;</td>

            <td>&nbsp;</td>

            <td>&nbsp;</td>

          </tr>

          <tr>

            <th scope="row">&nbsp;</th>

            <td>&nbsp;</td>

            <td>&nbsp;</td>

            <td>&nbsp;</td>

            <td>&nbsp;</td>

            <td>&nbsp;</td>

            <td>&nbsp;</td>

                            <td>&nbsp;</td>

            <td>&nbsp;</td>

            <td>&nbsp;</td>

            <td>&nbsp;</td>

            <td>&nbsp;</td>

            <td>&nbsp;</td>

          </tr>

          <tr>

            <th scope="row">&nbsp;</th>

            <td>&nbsp;</td>

            <td>&nbsp;</td>

            <td>&nbsp;</td>

            <td>&nbsp;</td>

            <td>&nbsp;</td>

            <td>&nbsp;</td>

                            <td>&nbsp;</td>

            <td>&nbsp;</td>

            <td>&nbsp;</td>

            <td>&nbsp;</td>

            <td>&nbsp;</td>

            <td>&nbsp;</td>

          </tr>

          <tr>

            <th scope="row">&nbsp;</th>

            <td>&nbsp;</td>

            <td>&nbsp;</td>

            <td>&nbsp;</td>

            <td>&nbsp;</td>

            <td>&nbsp;</td>

            <td>&nbsp;</td>

                            <td>&nbsp;</td>

            <td>&nbsp;</td>

            <td>&nbsp;</td>

            <td>&nbsp;</td>

            <td>&nbsp;</td>

            <td>&nbsp;</td>

          </tr>

          <tr>

            <th scope="row">&nbsp;</th>

            <td>&nbsp;</td>

            <td>&nbsp;</td>

            <td>&nbsp;</td>

            <td>&nbsp;</td>

            <td>&nbsp;</td>

            <td>&nbsp;</td>

                            <td>&nbsp;</td>

            <td>&nbsp;</td>

            <td>&nbsp;</td>

            <td>&nbsp;</td>

            <td>&nbsp;</td>

            <td>&nbsp;</td>

          </tr>

          <tr>

            <th scope="row">&nbsp;</th>

            <td>&nbsp;</td>

            <td>&nbsp;</td>

            <td>&nbsp;</td>

            <td>&nbsp;</td>

            <td>&nbsp;</td>

            <td>&nbsp;</td>

                            <td>&nbsp;</td>

            <td>&nbsp;</td>

            <td>&nbsp;</td>

            <td>&nbsp;</td>

            <td>&nbsp;</td>

            <td>&nbsp;</td>

          </tr>

          <tr>

            <th scope="row">&nbsp;</th>

            <td>&nbsp;</td>

            <td>&nbsp;</td>

            <td>&nbsp;</td>

            <td>&nbsp;</td>

            <td>&nbsp;</td>

            <td>&nbsp;</td>

            <td>&nbsp;</td>

            <td>&nbsp;</td>

            <td>&nbsp;</td>

            <td>&nbsp;</td>

            <td>&nbsp;</td>

            <td>&nbsp;</td>

          </tr>

        </table>



    </div>

    <div style="clear:both"></div>

</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Well just put the inner div outside the outer div and align the inner div which is now the outer div to the outer div which is, of course, now the inner div and your inner div will appear on top of the old inner div but we know it's secretly the outer div.

Answer (score 0):

you would like to try DataTables jQuery plugin to handle this problem:
http://datatables.net/

Comment: mmm interesting...how do i use this?

Comment: I am trying to use this tool on the table but am not getting anywhere. Trying to use there scrolling example.

Comment: <br/><br/> The table i am using have row headers, will is still work?